# SecurityException sending broadcast from Java on OS X

Tags: java, macos, sockets, permissions, broadcast

I'm trying to send a broadcast from java on my mac.  This seems like it should work, but I'm getting a SecurityException.  I've verified that there isn't a SecurityManager installed, and tried running my class using sudo.

The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    SocketAddress sockAddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.255",
            4000);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    bb.put(new Byte("1"));
    DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
    channel.send(bb, sockAddr);
}
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.sendFromNativeBuffer(DatagramChannelImpl.java:301)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:281)
    at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.send(DatagramChannelImpl.java:250)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that you're not using a DatagramSocket for this, rather than a DatagramChannel - the channel is the underlying implementation of the socket, but may not have everything set up in order to perform the broadcast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done a little googling, you need to tell the socket that the DatagramChannel is using that it's a broadcast Channel using the code:

```
channel.socket().setBroadcast(true);
```

I think it's just that you need to set the broadcast socket option on the 'channel', which is the underlying O/S socket. Evidently this will be doable from the channel level once java7 comes out, but currently you need to access the DatagramSocket to set the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That's `SocketException` not `SecurityException` (or `AccessControlException`). Seems that the OS isn't allowing your process to send that datagram.